# What is the purpose of Angular ElementRef nativeElement?

Tags: angular, element

I'm more familiar with DOM nodes and I guess the type 'Element'. (you'd have to search on "interface Element" in Typescript library [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts) here).
 I had thought that the nativeElement of ElementRef and Element was one and the same but they are not:

I'm aware of the API's

- [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html)
- [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html)
- [Renderer2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer2-class.html)

But the purpose of these mystifies me. (I'm more familiar with the likes of JQuery than Angular atm).

Comment: You probably don't need these unless you're doing something special. I'd suggest spending your time on more immediately relevant Angular topics. The most frequent use of `ElementRef` is by people who can't get their heads around the fact that they're not programming in jQuery any more,. It's hardly ever necessary in properly written Angular programs.

Comment: So what if you want to get the height of elements? Why for example do we have ElementRef at all if we just can use Element

Comment: For Angular to work reliably, you need to avoid working directly with the DOM yourself. When it is absolutely necessary, you should obtain an element through the `ElementRef` interface. Read the page at https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html for the various caveats that apply to using this. With regard to the height, why do you want to get that?

Comment: To do pagination. So I need to work out the records of per page I can fit into a list without the need for scrolling. I'm using Angular within the context of an Ionic Project. See here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874369/breadcrumb-pagination-in-ionic-2-3-angular2-4

Comment: I can see this as one way of getting height. let listmhpx:String = document.defaultView.
      getComputedStyle( document.getElementById("list") ).
      getPropertyValue('min-height'); // comes back like 50px
    let listmh:number = parseInt(listmhpx.substr(0, listmhpx.length-2));

Comment: I am looking to see if there is more of an Angular or Ionic way of doing this.

Comment: The records per page has to be calculated because different mobile devices will have differing screen (viewport) sizes.

Comment: It's not so uncommon the need for the reference of an element when, for example, you're using third party libraries which needs such a reference (like Charts.js, for example). It's much more elegant, scalable, and integrated to the framework the using of ElementRef + template reference variable (in a custom component) than using document.getElementById with a particular id identifying the html control.